# Eclipse editor won't open while opening pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu, pom.xml

I have just installed Ubuntu 15.10 and Eclipse.
As soon as I opened Eclipse, I went to : 
*Help -> Install New Software...*

Then I set: *Work with: Indigo Update Site - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/* 
I search for the plugin *m2e* and I have installed 
General Purpuse Tools -> m2e - Maven integration for Eclipse

I have already tried to reinstall both plug-in m2e and Eclipse, but I still got the same error **when I try to edit the pom.xml file**.

**Error:**

> Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

**Stack trace:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wst/sse/core/internal/provisional/IStructuredModel
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createPart(EditorManager.java:875)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:609)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:315)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2946)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2854)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2846)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2797)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2777)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:655)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:614)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:50)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while    
automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.core (312).
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:354)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.createInstance(ServiceComponent.java:493)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.createInstance(ServiceComponentProp.java:272)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:333)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.ServiceReg.getService(ServiceReg.java:53)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse$1.run(ServiceUse.java:141)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse.getService(ServiceUse.java:139)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:468)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:467)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:594)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.markers.MarkerUtils.addEditorHintMarkers(MarkerUtils.java:58)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.readMavenProject(ProjectRegistryManager.java:640)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:367)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:327)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:278)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenProjectManager.refresh(MavenProjectManager.java:58)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:120)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.SSECorePlugin.start() of bundle 
org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.utils.StringUtils.unpack(StringUtils.java:734)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningJob.projectHasNotBeenFullyScanned(TaskScanningJob.java:129)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningJob.addProject(TaskScanningJob.java:95)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningScheduler.enqueue(TaskScanningScheduler.java:138)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningScheduler.startup(TaskScanningScheduler.java:118)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.SSECorePlugin.start(SSECorePlugin.java:90)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.util.StringTokenizer
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 58 more
```

Comment: Indigo is a very old version. Why don't you try to install Mars or Luna instead?

Comment: From your stack trace:

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.util.StringTokenizer

That's because your classpath can't find ICU4J (https://wiki.eclipse.org/ICU4J).

Seems like a bad installation and might need to reinstall.   Go with Luiggi's response and install a newer version.

Comment: Ok solved installing Eclipse Mars, thanks!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I have the very same problem, and can't upgrade because I'm trying to run a project using Scala 2.9. Is there another solution ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks follow `@TristanEveritt` advice and reinstall your eclipse, or maybe you can upgrade it and try using Scala 2.9 (AFAIK this is no limitation when using Eclipse + Scala)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza at http://scala-ide.org/download/prev-stable.html I see 3.0.0 release is last supporting Scala 2.9, and only available on Indigo/Juno. My install is fresh from today. I'll try going after ICU4J. Thx, and if you have any other input it'll be very welcome.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza because that's what latest stable Ubuntu version ships.

Comment: @FrederickNord default doesn't mean "this is what I must use"

Comment: sure. But it's an answer to your question why anybody actually uses that version.  And I perfectly understand people being reluctant to install out-of-repository software.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Eclipse version is old and it is not compatible with plugin, try to install  updated version and see